# In SharePoint 2013, how can I use radio buttons in calculated type column of list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013, how can I use radio buttons in calculated type column of list? I have implemented below code in formula and keep its return type integer

```
_="&lt;input type='radio'  width='50px' name='DocumentRequired' id='rdRequired_' value='RequiredForChk' checked&gt;
  &lt;input type='radio' width='50px'  id='rdNotRequired_' name='DocumentRequired' value='NotRequiredForChk' &gt;"
```

But it is not working on radio button click.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Calculated column is for displaying data only, are you trying to tie that back to a click event?

Comment: Yes, toggle radio button on click..I have written click event on the radio button, but its not toggling.

Answer (score 2):

The `Allow Individual item checkboxes` should be un-ticked in the view. This would enable the click on the radio buttons.

[image]

The formula needs a slight change to work for multiple list items in the view. The list item ID needs to be added to the name attribute to make it unique for each item.

```
=CONCATENATE("<input type='radio' width='50px' name='DocumentRequired",ID,"' id='rdRequired' value='RequiredForChk' checked> <input type='radio' width='50px' id='rdNotRequired_' name='DocumentRequired", [ID], "' value='NotRequiredForChk' >")
```

The output is below. The radio buttons can be toggled. The click event can also be added for further action.

[image]